# What is the best solution for making a responsive "hero" image?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem getting a hero image to meet the expectations of the client.

On desktop view, the image fits in the hero `div` as expected and appealing to the client, however as the viewport gets smaller, on mobile, parts of the image gets cut off to retain the ratio of the image. The client does not like that.

I can't make the width and height 100% because the image will become distorted. If I set width to 100% and height to auto, the image still gets cut off in certain areas, Or the image gets smaller in height than the container, leaving a lot of white space. Is there a recommended solution to fix this problem?

Is it recommended to use a background image for the hero image, and style appropriately?

Is it better to have multiple sized images and use `<picture></picture>` to display different images based on screen size?

Or use CSS3 vh, vw units?

Should I just use media queries to adjust the height of the hero container?

Should I just get an image from the client that is the right proportion for the hero container?

```html
<div class="hero-container" style="width: 100%;display: inline-block;">
    <img src="https://imgurl">
</div>
```

```css
.hero-container {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
}

.hero-container img {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: #999;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code to create a **[Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)** ?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: yes, we need to see code ;)

Comment: @K_Bee, use media queries to resize the image and the container if needed. you are always going to run into issues like this as every device is a different size now (pixels) but media queries are the solution. some light reading on stack and W3schools should get you your answer.

Comment: @sao Thank you for pointing that out. I'll play around with that as well.

Comment: no problem, response to this thread if you get stuck. cheers

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been put on hold. It seems like a reasonable question to me. I think perhaps if the question were rephrased so it doesn't sound like you are canvasing opinions it might get re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at using a background image and setting it to `cover`:

(NB: I've put the background-image in the html's inline styling because I've assumed it could be dynamic.)

```css
.hero-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
  /*background-attachment:fixed; (removed)*/
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container" style="background-image: url(http://placeimg.com/640/480/people?t=1571230744264)">
</div>
```

I don't fully understand the client's expectations but perhaps setting a minimum and maximum height will help. Additionally you could add some media-queries to set specific min/max for mobile devices.

```css
html,body {
margin:0; min-height:100%; height:100%;
}
.hero-container {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  height:300px;
  max-height:50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container" style="background-image: url(http://placeimg.com/640/480/people?t=1571230744264)">
</div>
```

Comment: this definitely made the image more scalable. I'm still losing some parts of the image, but what I understand from a comment above, that behavior is inevitable to some extent. Thank you for sharing. I did not use the fixed background however. I was not looking for the parallax effect.

Comment: @k_Bee its the `background-attachment:fixed;` that giving the parallax effect. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

upd: i've wrote it before you posted the code

I think, that the img-fluid bootstrap class is an easiest way to do that.

```
...
<body>
<img src="img/yourhero.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive hero image">

</body>
```

this class adds  this css to your img:

```
img {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```